# How to form shuffled batches in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, batch-processing

I have a list of 100k entries and would like to split them into 10k shuffled batches. How to do this?

I found a function [shuffle](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) in `sklearn`, and it has a parameter of `n_samples`. But I don't see any guarantee, that this batch will cover all set.

I would like to take random batches from the entire set but doesn't repeat them until all samples taken. Is this possible?

Comment: The name ```shuffle``` tells you what it's doing and within your link, the alias ```resample(*arrays, replace=False)``` is more verbose``` ,  ```replace=False``` is the keyword! (should be described in python's random docs or numpy's random docs). This function (you linked) is more general and therefore ```n_samples``` matter of course so i don't see a special reason to use it compared to the simple alternatives using python's standard shuffle or numpy's shuffle (the former beeing shown by Ecir's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
from random import shuffle
def batches(entries):
    shuffle(entries)
    for i in range(0, len(entries), 10000):
        yield entries[i:i+10000]
```

Comment: How to use this while implementing `def __next__(self)`?

Comment: @Dims Sorry, not sure I follow: it's much easier to `yield` than to `__next__`..?

Comment: @jsalonen no it's ok, answer is accepted; it was just unexpected way for me